# How do i achieve a path alias in yii

Tags: php, yii

As per this link i have almost managed to achieve the structure. But the path alias is confusing me. Could somebody explain me how can i achieve this.

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/155/the-directory-structure-of-the-yii-project-site/#hh5

I want my controller in frontend to access these models from common folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`setPathOfAlias()` of YiiBase class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/YiiBase#setPathOfAlias-detail), to set a path alias:

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('site', $site);
```

You can do this in frontend's config *main.php* :

```
$site=dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))); // this will give you the / directory
Yii::setPathOfAlias('site', $site);

return array(
    // the config array
    // incase you want to autoload the models from common
    'import'=>array(
        'site.common.models.*'
    )
);
```

As asked without auto-loading, in this case you'll have to include the model first, and only then can you instantiate it. To include we can use `Yii::import($alias)` , which actually does almost the same thing([from guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.namespace#importing-classes)):

> The class definition being imported is actually not included until it is referenced for the first time (implemented via PHP autoloading mechanism).

So to use a DummyModel class which is defined in *common/models/* :

```
Yii::import('site.common.models.DummyModel');
$model = new DummyModel;
```

I would suggest going with auto-loading in the main.php config itself, there is no performance drop in specifying that import array, since the model will be included only if, and when it is referenced.

Comment: the best way will be to go for auto-load, which means the class will be included **only** when it is referred to. but otherwise you'll have to first import it, and then use it, will update answer.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to define your own path alias is to add 'aliases' array in */config/main.php*:

```
return array(
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name'=>'Project name',
    'aliases'=>array(
        'myalias'=>'/path/to/some/folder',
    ),
    'import'=>array(
        'myalias.models.*'
    )
    ...
```

And then anywhere in your code you can get the path to your alias:

```
echo Yii::getPathOfAlias('myalias');
```

More info on aliases [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.namespace).